# Converting php to Classic-ASP

Tags: php, asp-classic

Can someone please help me convert these two pieces of code from PHP to Classic-ASP...??

```
<?php  $show_popup = 0; if(!isset($_COOKIE['jquery_popup'])){setcookie('jquery_popup','jQuery Popup',time() + 120);
       $show_popup = 1;
    }
?>
```

and then to call the variable from above:

```
<?php
    if($show_popup == 1){
?>

SOME OF MY CONTENT

<?php
}
?>
```

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%
  show_popup=0
  if Request.Cookies("jquery_popup")="" then 
    Response.Cookies("jquery_popup")="jQuery Popup"
    Response.Cookies("jquery_popup").expires = DateAdd("h",2,Now())
    show_popup=1
  end if
%>
```

Then

```
<%
  if show_popup=1 then
%>

 BLAH

<%
  end if
%>
```

Comment: Thanx for the response pee2pee.  Unfortunately, it is not working. Should the "jQuery Popup" be inside quotation marks in the line `Response.Cookies("jquery_popup")=jQuery Popup`....???